# Orchard - How to show more fields of a content item in a summery view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Let's say I have a product to which I've added an image field called SmallImage.

When I show a list of products, I want the small image to be in the view.
When I go to the list of divisions I get the default summary view, like so:

```
<article class="content-item @contentTypeClassName">
    <header>
        @Display(Model.Header)
        @if (Model.Meta != null) {
        <div class="metadata">
            @Display(Model.Meta)
        </div>
        }
    </header>
    @Display(Model.Content)
    @if(Model.Footer != null) {
    <footer>
        @Display(Model.Footer)
    </footer>
    }
</article>
```

How does **@Display(Model.Content)** generate the HTML?

Where is the **.cshtml** file I can put **@Html.Image(Model.SmallImage)** into?

## EDIT

Ok, I found the property off the model: **Model.ContentItem.Product.SmallImage.FileName**, so I just need to know where the template file is.

THX!
Dan

Bonus Question:
Using the designer tools in any list view.  Go to **Zone[Content].Content.List**.  Under **Shape** is says there are two alternate views.  One is MyTheme/Views/List.Html.  If you click on "create" it says *The relative virtual path 'Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes::List' is not allowed here.* Does that mean that there really isn't an alternate for this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manually created the file that was giving me the error in the bonus question and this gets me the image. (**List-url-products.cshtml**)

```
 <div>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <div>@item.Title.ToString()</div>

        var division = item.ContentItem.Division;
        var smallImage = (Contrib.ImageField.Fields.ImageField) division.ListImage;

        if(smallImage.FileName != null)
        {
            <div>@Html.Image(smallImage.FileName, null, new { Width=smallImage.Width, Height=smallImage.Height }) </div>    
        }   
    }
 </div>
```

Comment: Alternately, you can edit placement.info file it include specific fields or parts as documented here: http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Understanding-placement-info.ashx